# Can an unauthorized managed package be installed over an appexchange approved managed package in salesforce?

Tags: package, salesforce

We are creating a managed package and want to list it on appexchange.
However, we would like to know salesforce behaviour in below situation since we couldn't find any conclusive docs:

1. If user has installed appexchange managed package v1. And we have
   released new managed package version v2 which is not authorized by
   appexchange currently.    If we provide this managed package link to
   user, can it be installed over appexchange product v1? What are the
   implications?     Can user later install any new version of package
   that is appexchange approved?

Answer (score 0):

> And we have released new managed package version v2 which is not authorized by appexchange currently.

If you have released a new version of the *same managed package*, yes, your users can upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0. If you are using second-generation packaging, there has to be an ancestry line between 1.0 and 2.0 (this is always true for first-generation packaging).

I'm not sure what you mean about "authorized by AppExchange". Possibly you're saying that 2.0 has not been sent through the ISV Security Review process.

> If we provide this managed package link to user, can it be installed over appexchange product v1?

Yes.

> What are the implications?

I would need to be clearer on what you mean to assess implications.

> Can user later install any new version of package that is appexchange approved?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently, I am working on first generation package only. What I understand here is both unauthorized(not submitted for security review) and authorized managed packages are considered same with respect to their working and installation. If package is approved by salesforce security, it becomes eligible to be listed on appexchange and becomes publically available. Kindly let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Just submit version 2 through Security Review. Once 1.0 has passed subsequent versions are typically auto approved until your application is selected for a full rereview.